# facebook API - batch requests to one request to get image dimensions

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, request, batch-processing, dimensions

i am reading the whole public feed of an user with facebook graph api.
the way i get the feed is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/userid/feed
```

so, in this feed sometimes there are posted pictures which i also want to use in my app. problem is:
when i just load the image source, i am getting a very low quality image.
with facebook graph api it is possible to get image dimensions when i have the object_id of the picture/photo like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/objectid?fields=images
```

with this call i am getting the image with all dimensions and imagesource URL.

but for this i have to call a request again. how can i batch that together so that i can get the feed WITH the imagesTAG directly in first call?

i have tried to call first and second level but i didnt get any solution:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/userid/feed?id,name,message,object_id,picture,type{images}
```

anyway, i tried so much but i cant get the image resolutions with ONE call in that json return.

is this not possible with the graph api? or what i am doing wrong here?

thanks,
brush51

Answer (score 0):

Use this complex batch request to retrieve images (replace "me/home" with your request):

```
[{ "method":"GET","name":"me_home", "relative_url":"me/home?fields=object_id"}, { "method":"GET", "depends_on":"me_home", "relative_url":"?ids={result=me_home:$.data.*.object_id}"}]
```

But note that you will get only images hosted at Facebook.